# GUI with layout

Tags: java, swing

I have a jframe that contains three text fields and two radio button(for choosing of yes or no).

It should be like this:
[image]

But, with my code, it is this:
[image]

My code:

```
public class editFrame extends JFrame {

JButton saveButton;
JButton cancelButton;
JRadioButton radioB1;
JRadioButton radioB2;

public editFrame() {

    JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
    wrapper.add(createForm());
    add(wrapper, BorderLayout.WEST);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setBounds(100, 50, 500, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel createForm() {
    String[] labels = {"ID", "Name", "Date"};
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JTextField idtf = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField nametf = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField datetf = new JTextField(10);
    panel.add(idtf);
    panel.add(nametf);
    panel.add(datetf);

    radioB1 = new JRadioButton("Yes");
    radioB2 = new JRadioButton("No");
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(radioB1);
    group.add(radioB2);
    panel.add(radioB1);
    panel.add(radioB2);
    saveButton = new JButton("update");
    cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    panel.add(saveButton);
    panel.add(cancelButton);

    SpringLayout sL = new SpringLayout();
    panel.setLayout(sL);
    SpringUtilities.makeCompactGrid(panel, 3, 2, 100, 50, 15, 20);

    return panel;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editFrame edF = new editFrame();
        }
    });
}
```

The borrow Status text doesn't show beside the radio Buttons.
The second main problem is that I can not access text fields.

Comment: if you are using Netbeans IDE then it allows visual design for swing apps

Comment: @Abu Can you explain more?

Comment: are you using any IDE for development

Comment: @Abu, I use Netbeans IDE

Comment: then it should have a visual editor with drag-and-drop functionality for designing variuos components on jPanel

Comment: @Abu Yes, It has that feature, But i want create GUI by hand...

Comment: use that feature and then compare your implementation, because sometimes its very difficult to achieve by-hand

Comment: @Abu I highly dissagree about using GUI designers. He's never going to understand swing if he creates it by drag-and-drop.

Comment: @Sajjad- What I think that you need to go through the official swing visual layout tutorial . And start from the beginning , understand each Layout one by one . And then proceed with a GUI design. It is so easy believe me..

Comment: @VishalK I know that spring layout do this, But in my code, doesn't work...

Comment: @Sajjad-Have a look at this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html for `SpringLayout` , You would surely get your answer solved by that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the label for radios is not shown, because you don't create it and add it to panel. Create it and add it to panel before radioB1. Also, you should add some invisible (empy) label before radioB2 (or use some other filler component to fill the cell - perhaps this could help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler).

Also, you could add another filler component to panel instead of saveButton. Then I would create another panel (buttonPane), that would contain both save and cancel buttons and add this buttonPane to the main panel instead of cancelButton. The panel for buttons could use BoxLayout and in between buttons could be horizontal glue (as you can see in the link above).

That should be it. But there's one warning here. You are creating JTextFields in the loop in such way, that you cannot refer to them later, ie. when you will need to get the text. You should keep their references as individual variables, or add them to an array, so you can get the values, when the update button is pressed.